# Export/import jobs in Jenkins using jenkins-cli.jar and user authentication

Tags: curl, jenkins, cmd, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

There are many answers to this question but my question is slightly different.

What I tried

```
   java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://<user>:<API_Token>@server get-job myjob > myjob.xml
   java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://<user>:<password>@server get-job myjob > myjob.xml
```

But I got the error `anonymous` user error. So, how can authenticate user using jenkins-cli.jar command ?

```
hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Job/ExtendedRead permission
        at hudson.security.ACL.checkPermission(ACL.java:63)
```

I also tried,

```
$ curl -u <user>:<API_Token> http://server/ get-job myjob > myjob.xml
```

But, the it just dumps whole HTML page instead of job.xml file

Comment: The [Jenkins CLI documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI#JenkinsCLI-WorkingwithCredentials) shows how to use credentials. Short answer: use `--username` and `--password`.

Comment: To use curl, you should use the Jenkins REST API, not the CLI commands. Try `http://server/job/myjob/config.xml`

Comment: My mistake, the Jenkins CLI can only use an SSH key for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may sometimes need to log in first:

> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -noCertificateCheck -s https://localhost login --username=exporter --password=mypass
>
> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -noCertificateCheck -s https://localhost list-jobs
>
> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -noCertificateCheck -s https://localhost get-job myjob > myjob.xml

Comment: Fantastic   ✌, I didn't even get it jenkins-cli.jar help section.